# Como passar um valor para uma lista e deixa-lo estático?

Tags: c#, lista

Tenho uma lista de objetos que estou preenchendo-a da seguinte forma:

```
var props = type.GetRuntimeProperties();

var obj = new T();

for (int i = 0; i < readerCache.Count; i++)
{
    var prop = props.Single(x => x.GetColumnName().ToLower() == readerCache.ElementAt(i).Item1.ToLower());

    if (prop.GetCustomAttribute<Column>().Type == ColumnType.FK)
    {
        var method = typeof(SelectExtension).GetMethod("SelectSingle");

        var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(prop.PropertyType);

        prop.SetValue(obj, generic.Invoke(null, new object[] { dBManager, $"WHERE id = '{readerCache.ElementAt(i).Item2}'" }));
    }
    else
    {
        prop.SetValue(obj, readerCache.ElementAt(i).Item2);
    }

    if ((i + 1) % props.Count() == 0)
    {
        objList.Add(obj);
    }
}
```

Quando estou debugando, os objetos estão sendo preenchidos de forma correta, mas quando a lista termina de ser preenchida, todos os elementos estão iguais.

Minha suspeita é que esteja passando o objeto por referencia, e não por valor.

Por que isso acontece? Como consertar?

Comment: Você não deveria estar declarando `obj` dentro do loop?

Comment: Não poderia, pois o obj só está completo depois de ter passado algumas vezes pelo loop. Fazendo da forma que você disse iria instancia-lo o tempo todo.

Comment: Você tem algum campo que difere entre todos os objetos? Se sim só fazer um verificação

Answer (score 0):

Uma lista de [tipos de referência](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) nada mais é do que uma lista de referências. Isso significa que cada posição da lista guarda uma referência para o objeto ali inserido.

> Por que isso acontece?

```
var obj = new T();

for (int i = 0; i < readerCache.Count; i++)
{
    // Operações que possivelmente mudam a estrutura de 'obj' a cada iteração
    ...
    // Adição da referência de 'obj'
    objList.Add(obj);
}
```

Por mais que a estrutura do objeto `obj` mude dentro do laço de repetição, a referência continua sendo a mesma. Executando `objList.Add(obj)` você está sempre adicionando a referência do objeto inicial à lista, resultando em uma lista com várias referências do mesmo objeto (ou seja, todos os elementos são iguais).

> Como consertar?

1. Declare `obj` dentro do laço. Isso garante que cada objeto possui um endereço diferente na memória e consequentemente referências distintas serão adicionadas à lista de objetos.
2. Caso a primeira opção não seja possível, eu sugiro que você adicione à lista de objetos um **clone** do seu objeto.

Criar um clone de um objeto em C# pode ser problemático. Uma das soluções mais simples é por serialização e deserialização. Usando o framework [Newtonsoft Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), você pode fazer algo assim:

```
objList.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)));
```

Se quiser, você pode implementar um [método de extensão personalizado](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-implement-and-call-a-custom-extension-method)

```
public static T Clone<T>(this T source)
{
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source));
}
```

e em seguida usá-lo

```
objList.Add(obj.Clone());
```

Comment: Eu estava curioso se haveria outro caminho para essa pergunta, sua resposta confirma o que eu achava. Se o código fosse meu, eu reestruturaria para conseguir declarar o objeto dentro do loop.

Comment: Fiz da maneira que você falou, mas o problema é que os subobjetos estão vindo nulos -> https://imgur.com/a/XOTC3